# Facebook sdk js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-chat

How to avoid Facebook xfbml.customerchat.js conflict with sdk.js?
I want to use 2 apps on my website:

1. Facebook live chat
2. Facebook graph api login
   Live chat is working. But login not working. https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js not including
   with FB.login() called before FB.init() error. How to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: please add the exact error message, and the relevant code (how you implement both)

Comment: You mean, two different _app ids_?  That is not really easily possible. (Explain your exact scenario in more detail, if that’s the case.) If you are just talking about using one app id, and functionality from both SDKs - you don’t need both, the customer chat SDK includes all the code of the “normal” one already.